# Unable to integrate facebook 4.0 into eclipse

Tags: android, facebook

I want to integrate facebook in my app. i downloaded the latest sdk (4.0) but i am unable to integrate in my app. the facebook sdk is showing errors. im not using the gradle process or maven to import fb sdk in my app. i want to do it with existing app code.

When i am using the previous version of facebook, i am not getting any errors. it is working fine. when i try to add the latest version of facebook, im unable to do it. please any one help me if anything has changed in facebook sdk latest version.?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what error you're getting?